# Change Billing and Shipping Address to cater for legal requirements (at least in Germany)

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Currently the Shipping and the Billing Address on the invoice just read DE in the Stack Overflow Teams admin UI. This creates endless hassles in Germany where at least the billing address must contain the full, real address of the legal entity.

In the Billing & Account screen I cannot find a way to change this. How is it done?

Comment: Hey @Harald'R'! We've seen this issue come up with a couple of other German companies. If you email teams-support [at] stackoverflow, we'll be able to fix this issue for you. sorry for the inconvenience!!

Comment: @ChanceHeath is there a more permanent fix coming?

Comment: @Pureferret absolutely! I don't have a timeline for you at this moment, but having billing address not working properly for the entire country of Germany is not tenable for us.

Comment: 6-8 weeks probably

Comment: what is the meaning of DE?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson It's the country code for Germany.